# Windows 7: проблема с беспроводной сетью

Tags: windows, windows-7, wifi, сеть

Здравствуйте

Имеется странная необъяснимая проблема с машиной под Windows 7. Переустановка системы крайне нежелательна, а творятся странные вещи. Симптомы и факты:

- не работает всё что связано с внешней сетью, включая DNS
- внутренняя сеть работает, так я могу обратиться к сетевому диску или роутеру;
- ping на внешние ресурсы не проходит, на внутренние работает;
- явление непостоянное, но очень частое, возникает периодически;
- все другие устройства во время таких затупов работают отлично, нагрузка на роутер обычная, расход ресурсов обычный;
- сначала я подумал, что неисправен wifi-адаптер, но когда я его сменил, то с другим симптомы такие же;
- при загрузке на этой машине под Linux указанная проблема не возникает, стало быть проблема вероятно не связана с железом;
- все настройки в норме, пробовал пересоздавать соединение, переключать разные флажки настроек, но ничего не помогает;
- по неизвестной причине на какое-то время помогает перезагрузка wifi-роутера, однако, как я уже говорил выше, все дургие устройства (ноутбук на Win7, ноутбук на Linux, два телефона на Android) прекрасно работают с этим же роутером в то самое время, как на проблемной машине проявляется проблема;
- простое переподключение сети, переподключение устройства, перезагрузка компьютера не помогает, так что перезагрузка роутера является на данный момент единственным воркэраундом;
- проблема затрагивает не только DNS: если я обращаюсь по внешнему точному адресу, то просто не удаётся соединиться так будто пакеты просто теряются.

Такое ощущение, будто нарушается какая-то таблица маршрутов или что-то такое, что приводит к потерям пакетов, направленных именно наружу, но я понятия не имею как диангостировать такие неполадки под win.

Видел описание аналогичной проблемы на форуме инфолана, но там не было ответа. Если есть какие-то идеи, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: ip-адреса заданы статически или через DHCP? Влияет ли отключение антивируса/брандмауэра на сеть? Включен ли фаервол на роутере?

Comment: DHCP. Не влияет. Фаервол включён, но там нет никаких особенных правил. Кроме того, это не объясняет то, что эффект имеет периодический характер. Пакетный фильтр либо всегда бы пропускал, либо всегда не пропускал бы.

Comment: Насколько часто возникает эта проблема? Если возникают проблемы в том числе и с DNS, можно попробовать вручную очистить кэш (ipconfig /flushdns) или вообще отключить dns-кеширование. Также можно попробовать прописать альтернативный dns-сервер (гугл 8.8.8.8, скайднс 193.58.251.251, любой другой днс-сервер)

Answer (score 1):

Включенный на роуторе (да и на компе) firewall объясняет то, что эффект имеет периодический характер. Вы забываете про интеллектуальные системы обнаружения вторжений. Ну а если Вы используете Avast или Nod32, то тут вообще всё понятно.

Comment: несогласен, периодический эффект не есть симптом файерволлов, антивирусов и систем обнаружения вторжений.

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема на ноутбуке с WIndows 7. Проблема крылась в средствах безопасности, а ля антивирус Касперского и брандмауэр Windows. Необходимо проверить, чтобы домашняя сеть была указана в антивирусе и настройках сетевых подключений именно как "Домашняя" или "Доверенная".

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

1. посмотрел бы таблицу маршрутизации - на WindowsXP+ - netstat -rn
2. посмотрел бы что с ифейсами - ipconfig /all
3. посмотрел бы на таблицу arp - arp -a
4. посмотрел бы tcpdump  - для винды есть утилитка соответствующая (которую надо ставить отдельно, в состав системы не входит)

Думаю, что в купе эта информация покажет вам "слабое звено"

Answer (score 1):

Такое же было. Модем в роутере 2е 7ры днс и тп, проблемы с интернетом. На одном из компьютеров поставил 8ку, работает шикарно и без предыдущих проблем. Кстати, при 7ке и ХР тоже проблем таковых не возникало.